# Input and Alternate Audio Output not working

Tags: 10.10, sound

I own Toshiba Satellite Pro C650 and it is running Ubuntu 10.10. I also have Windows 7 installed on other drive.

My notebook has built-in speakers and an audio output jack. In Windows 7, when I plugin an my headphones into the jack, the speakers stop and the sound is played through the headphones. But, it doesn't work in Ubuntu. Even the Hardware tab in Sound Preferences dialog box shows only one audio device. Can you please help me out?

P.S: I've just migrated from Windows 7 to Ubuntu. But I cannot uninstall Windows 7 because I need the "mute speaker, play headphones" functionality as I do not want to disturb others. This is the only reason, Windows 7 is still there on my laptop.

Edit: I wasn't clear. Headphones do not work at all. There is also another problem: My input device does not work.

Comment: Do the headphones work when you plug them in? There should be a drop down for you to select the source for the output of the music in the sound preferences.

Comment: No, the headphones do not work at all. The sound preferences box shows only one device.

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards